# Google Login Passport problem with cookie

Tags: reactjs, node.js, session-cookies, passport-google-oauth2

I implemented the google login with passport in the following way but I get this error: Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url..etc.. The combined size of the name and value must be less than or equal to 4096 characters.

This is the code

Passport.js

```
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");
const CLIENT_ID =
  "";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "";
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
```

Auth.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");

router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      error: false,
      message: "Successfully Loged In",
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ error: true, message: "Not Authorized" });
  }
});

router.get("/login/failed", (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({
    error: true,
    message: "Log in failure",
  });
});

router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}home`,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
  })
);

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL);
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("dotenv").config();


require("dotenv").config();
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passportStrategy = require("./googleauth/passport");

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["chiavecookie"],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
  })
);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const authRoute = require("./googleauth/auth");

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

LoginPage.js (Frontend)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NavBar from "../../Shared/Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import TextComponent from "../../Shared/Components/TextComponent";
import MainNavigation from "../../Shared/Pages/MainNavigation";

const LoginPage = (props) => {

  const googleAuth = () => {
    window.open("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/google", "_self");
  };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar />
        <TextComponent titolo={"Login"} />
        <div className="center">
          <button onClick={googleAuth}>Login</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

I cleaned the cookies and downloaded working versions of code from the web but those don't work either